# Is there a quicker way than SUMPRODUCT? 2-way lookup sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

O365

Vertical column C has unique values, horizontal row 3 has duplicates.

I need to sum up the columns to condense the array as shown in row 9 to 13.

Currently using this formula in D10: `=SUMPRODUCT($D$4:$H$7*($D$3:$H$3=D$9)*($C$4:$C$7=$C10))`

Every change I make takes 30 sec to calculate even with 16 threads churning. Turning to manual calc is not an option.

I cannot use Pivots or PQ.

The two arrays are quite large, so I'm looking for a **faster way to calculate** (via formula).

Thoughts: SUM FILTER, SUMIF INDEX MATCH OFFSET

**Final Solution @Scott Craner :** `=SUMIF($D$3:$H$3,D$9,INDEX($D$4:$H$7,MATCH($C10,$C$4:$C$7,0),0))`

[image: SUMPRODUCT]

Comment: What are the actual sizes of the ranges in question? I assume you're limiting the ranges passed to the formulas to include only the rows/columns with data?

Comment: @JosWoolley Source array is about 350 col by 250 row. Result array is 30 col by 250 row. all cells have data.

Comment: not sure if quicker or not: `=SUMIF($D$3:$H$3,D$9,INDEX($D$4:$H$7,MATCH($C10,$C$4:$C$7,0),0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner after testing, this is way faster (2 sec only). thank you

Comment: @spacej3di the answer needs to be in the answer section, not as part of the question. You can create an answer and mark it as correct or let Scott Craner to do if he wants. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH in a SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF($D$3:$H$3,D$9,INDEX($D$4:$H$7,MATCH($C10,$C$4:$C$7,0),0))
```

It should be way quicker as it is doing far less calculations.

Answer (score 1):

So, even further to Scott’s formula, you can still squeeze a *ton* of additional speed out of this, *on the condition that C10:C14 is simply equal C4:C7.* If they are the same *values* in the same *order* then there is no need to do INDEX/MATCH, you can just use a direct relative row reference. This will be *profoundly* faster yet.

- C10’s formula is `=C4:C7` and let it spill.
- D9’s formula is `=UNIQUE(D3:H3)` and let it spill.
- D10’s formula is `=SUMIF($D$3:$H$3, D$9, $D4:$H4)`. Copy it right and down.